# VB.Net / SQL Multiple Variables for HTML Email

Tags: vb.net, variables, concatenation

I was wondering if someone can offer advice regarding the following:

I have a piece of code that generates an email containing variables:

```
 Dim oApp As Outlook._Application
    oApp = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem
    oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

    oMsg.Subject = EmailSubjectSTR

    Dim usersignature As String = "test"

    oMsg.HTMLBody = EmailStr



    oMsg.To = "" & EmailToSTR.ToString & ""

    oMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "" & EmailFromSTR & ""


    Dim sSource2 As String = "" & EmailAttachment1STR & ""
    Dim sDisplayName2 As String = "test"
    Dim sBodyLen2 As String = oMsg.Body.Length
    Dim oAttachs2 As Outlook.Attachments = oMsg.Attachments
    Dim oAttach2 As Outlook.Attachment
    oAttach2 = oAttachs2.Add(sSource2, , sBodyLen2 + 1, sDisplayName2)

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        oMsg.Display()
    Else
        oMsg.Send()
    End If
```

The value of EmailStr is:

```
    oMsg.HTMLBody = "<span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:""Calibri"" '>Hello, blah blah blah <br>" & UserSignature & " </span>"
```

When I Swap -  oMsg.HTMLBody = EmailStr to the below it works fine and instead of displaying " & UserSignature & " in the email body it will actually show my email signature because it looks back to SQL for the " & UserSignature & " Variable.

```
    EmailSTR = oMsg.HTMLBody = "<span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:""Calibri"" '>Hello, blah blah blah <br>" & UserSignature & " </span>"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why does it pick up variables and insert them to the body of the email when I use the actual value: of oMsg.HTMLBody = "<span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:""Calibri"" '>Hello, blah blah blah <br>" & UserSignature & " </span>" but not when I load a string with the same value.

Comment: I'm not sure but **The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string.** so maybe you should add the **<html> </html>** tags

Comment: On the example I posted I missed the HTML Tags but they are present on my other template emails and do not work either.

Comment: you missed something: `oMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` and remember the: `<body></body>`

Comment: Thanks Mederic, I have tried your suggestions but still no luck I think ill have to find a different way of sending emails containing variables.

Comment: On the MSDN they pass by a variable as well so I guess just do that even if it adds a line. Best of luck

Comment: I have now changed to the following which is producing the emails correctly if anyone else has this issue:


        Dim value1 As String = EmailStr.Replace(""" & UserSignature & """, UserSignature)
        EmailStr = value1
        Dim value2 As String = value1.Replace("" & TextBox12.Text & "", TextBox12.Text.ToString)
        EmailStr = value2